# Vue class component can't access data properties from constructor

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to use Vue with typescript but am getting an error, saying that my member variable is undefined.

```
import { Component, Vue, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import UploadApi from './UploadApi';
import ApiConfig from '../../api/api.config';

@Component
export default class UploadCard extends Vue {
  uploading = false;

  private uploads: Array<Upload> = [];

  private api: UploadApi = new UploadApi(ApiConfig.get());

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.getUploads();
  }

  private getUploads() {
    // const loading = this.$store.state.vs.loading();
    // mimic http request
    console.log(this.$data);
    console.log(this.uploading);
    this.api.getUploads().then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
```

Here for example it is saying this.api is undefined, does anyone know about this?

Comment: Hi! I’m not sure about your question - do you mind sharing for code, or perhaps what your UploadApimofule looks like? We’ll be able to help you better :D

Comment: The lifecycle model worked, using created instead of constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a constructor, use the [lifecycle methods](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks) to do setup tasks. For example, replace your constructor with `created` or `mounted`:

```
created() {
    this.getUploads();
}
```

Please see [the docs](https://class-component.vuejs.org/guide/caveats.html#always-use-lifecycle-hooks-instead-of-constructor) for more details.

Comment: Ok so, the class here is a bit of red-herring? you ignore the constructor but use the lifecycle events.

Comment: Yes, I added a link to the docs: https://class-component.vuejs.org/guide/caveats.html#always-use-lifecycle-hooks-instead-of-constructor